# ios5 , TSAlertView don't pop up, who can tell me why?

Tags: iphone, uibutton, ios5, xcode4.2

it is a Single View Application, and I just add a button above it
when I click the button, it will show the key board. 
and I can't auto release TSAlertView in onBtn function.
Who can tell me why, I am really confused.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIButton *btn  = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(30, 30, 100., 50);
    [btn setTitle:@"Test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn addTarget:self action:(@selector(onBtn:)) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [btn setBackgroundColor:UIColor.greenColor];
    [self.view addSubview:btn];
}

-(void)onBtn:(id)sender{
    TSAlertView* av = [[TSAlertView alloc] init];
    av.title = @"Test";
    av.message = @"This is a test";
    [av addButtonWithTitle:@"cancel"];
    [av addButtonWithTitle:@"rename"];
    av.style =TSAlertViewStyleInput;
    av.buttonLayout = TSAlertViewButtonLayoutNormal;
    av.usesMessageTextView =NO;
    av.width = 0.0;
    av.maxHeight = 0.0;
    [av show];
}
```

[image]

Comment: TSAlertView defaults to a normal view.  There must be something else in your code causing this.  Can you show the rest of your onBtn method?

Comment: @Havt I have post the rest of onBtn method, please give me a hand, thanks

Comment: The keyboard appears because some UI object that wants the keyboard has become the first responder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the `AlertView`'s style to `Input`, it'll set it as the first responder and show keyboard.

```
av.style =TSAlertViewStyleInput;
```

Try another style. ;)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I find in TSAlertView, it resign text field FirstResponder. While now the problem is when click the button, it don't pop up the alert view, it just show the keyboard.

Comment: @Jane_Meng I tried the Demo the author gave, even comment out the resignFirstResponder is OK. The key one is `av.style = _hasInputFieldSwitch.on ? TSAlertViewStyleInput : TSAlertViewStyleNormal;`. If you turn on the `InputFieldSwitch`, it'll use TSAlertViewStyleInput and show keyboard, other wise, just show alertView as normal(In this case, use style:`TSAlertViewStyleNormal`).

Comment: BTW, you can download it and test yourself. ;)

Comment: Yes, you are right, thanks very much. Now I know why it show the keyboard. But when I click the button, I don't pop up the alertView. and I have no idea about this. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Hi @Jane_Meng, what have you changed in code? Maybe you can print a log in `onBtn:` to show if it is called. Then make sure you do call `[av show];` to show the alert view when the button clicked.

Comment: hi, the OnBtn: is called. and after click test button, it also print following logs: TSAlertView: TSAlertOverlayWindow dealloc|| TSAlertView: TSAlertViewController dealloc || TSAlertView: TSAlertOverlayWindow dealloc. But the alertView never pop up

Comment: @Jane_Meng have you changed the code? Remember you can show the alertView with keyboard before. Can you paste you new code?

Comment: hi @Kjuly, it always only shows the keyboard, no alertView, please refer to attachment picture.

Comment: hi @Kjuly, I have resolve the problem. I go into my projects build settings. Search for automatic reference counting. Once I find it set the value to "NO". then re-build, it is OK. I don't know why, but now it work correctly.

Comment: @Jane_Meng, Cheers! But I think issue still exists, maybe you delloc the alertView as soon as it shown(just a guess). `ARC is done by the compiler and should be thought of as a wizard or helper that checks all of your code and inserts the correct retain and release statements for you`, I'm not familiar with it, but you can refer to some docs on the ARC by yourself. :)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used the TSAlertView but after browsing through the code, you try a hack.  After you call show, try resigning the first responder:

```
[av show];
[av.inputTextField resignFirstResponder];
```

This may or may not work.  If not and you really need the keyboard hidden you might want to modify the code regarding the notifications in the TSAlrtView class itself.